# Error in python microservices with connexion+Flask+Swagger

Tags: python, connexion

I'm trying to make a microservice with python, I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ssola/building-microservices-with-python-part-i-5240a8dcc2fb)

But I'm getting this error:

```
"flask_app.py", line 115, in run
    raise Exception('Server {} not recognized'.format(self.server))
Exception: Server 9090 not recognized
```

Project structure:

[image: project structure image]

**App.py** file code

```
from connexion.resolver import RestyResolver
import connexion

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = connexion.App(__name__, 9090, specification_dir='swagger/')
    app.add_api('my_super_app.yaml', resolver=RestyResolver('api'))
    app.run()
```

**my_super_app.yaml** file code

```
swagger: "2.0"

info:
  title: "My first API"
  version: "1.0"

basePath: /v1.0

paths:
  /items/:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'Fetch a list of items'
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Item'

definitions:
  Item:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      name: { type: string }
```

**items.py** file code

```
items = {
    0: {"name": "First item"}
}


def search() -> list:
    return items
```

Comment: The error is on line 5 of `app.py`, obviously. Seriously, how are we supposed to help if you didn't share _any_ of your code?! Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: ok man, sorry, i'm going to post my code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok... i was able to solve this problem... the problem is in app.py, you must specify the variable port:

INCORRECT

```
app = connexion.App(__name__, 9090, specification_dir='swagger/')
```

CORRECT

```
app = connexion.App(__name__, port=9090, specification_dir='swagger/')
```

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of microservice frameworks in Python that would simplify a lot the code you have to write.

Try for example pymacaron (http://pymacaron.com/). Here is an example of an helloworld api implemented with pymacaron: https://github.com/pymacaron/pymacaron-helloworld

A pymacaron service requires you only to:
(1) write a swagger specification for your api (which is always a good starting point, whatever language you are using). Your swagger file describes the get/post/etc calls of your api and which objects (json dicts) they get and return, but also which python method in your code that implement the endpoint. 
(2) and implement your endpoints' methods.

Once you have done that, you get loads of things for free: you can package your code as a docker container, deploy it to amazon beanstalk, start asynchronous tasks from within your api calls, or get the api documentation with no extra work.

Comment: Exists similar proyects than pymacaron like https://github.com/python-microservices